# distinguish between chrome and opera

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, opera, conditional-statements

I have this javascript function that's supposed to open a different div in chrome than in other browsers. The proper div opens in firefox, internet explorer, safari, and chrome, but opera opens the chrome div instead of the other div. Is there a way to stop opera from performing the chrome function?

```
     function Browser() {
    var is_chrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;

      if (is_chrome) {
        document.getElementById('chrome').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('notchrome').style.display = 'none';
}
  }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the user agent string for opera vs chrome? Maybe you can identify something there.

Comment: What do you need those divs for? Browser detection is despised. Also, if you've got the latest Opera which builds on Blink as well it's fine to identify it as Chrome :-)

Comment: do you want a css hack that targets only opera? set that do display:none?

Comment: I agree with @Bergi - have you considered [detecting features instead of browsers](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/Optimizing_content_for_different_browsers:_the_RIGHT_way) for your particular use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read here you can see that you can look for the OPR string to identify Opera.

http://my.opera.com/ODIN/blog/2013/07/15/opera-user-agent-strings-opera-15-and-beyond

For example you can include it in your test like this:

```
var userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var is_chrome = userAgent.indexOf('chrome') > -1 && userAgent.indexOf('opr/') == -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

not to offend you. But, I think, if you check if it is only chrome and not opera, would break for other custom browsers built on chrome platform. Example Chinese QQ browser.

Rather, you can check if user agent contains "Chrome" in it and navigator.vendor contains "Google Inc." This gives you chrome precisely.

> var isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().search('chrome') != -1 && navigator.vendor.toLowerCase().search('google') != -1;

I use toLowerCase() inorder to keep things clean and subtle.

Comment: Doesn't work. _Opera_ , _Brave_ return `true` with (above). Specifically, `navigator.vendor.toLowerCase()` returns **`google inc.`**